# Passing a generic object with type that is derived from the required type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, arguments

Is it possible to pass a generic object as an argument with a class type that is derived from the expected class type?

The code below results in a compiler error, **`cannot convert from ItemObject<Equipment> to ItemObject<Item>`**, which I find odd because `Equipment` inherits from `Item`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public abstract class Item { }

public abstract class Equipment : Item { }

public class ItemObject<T> where T : Item { }

public class EquipmentManager
{
    ItemObject<Equipment> equipment = new ItemObject<Equipment>();

    public void Unequip()
    {
        Inventory.instance.AddItem(equipment);
    }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public static Inventory instance;
    List<ItemObject<Item>> items = new List<ItemObject<Item>>();

    public void AddItem(ItemObject<Item> _item)
    {
        items.Add(_item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t your Equipment class inherit from ItemObject<T> instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve that using covariance, which would allow you to use a more derived type. However that can only be applied to interfaces, so you would need to do something like this:

```cs
public abstract class Item { }

public abstract class Equipment : Item { }

public interface IItemObject<out T> where T : Item { }
public class ItemObject<T> : IItemObject<T> where T : Item { }

public class EquipmentManager {
    IItemObject<Equipment> equipment = new ItemObject<Equipment>();

    public void Unequip() {
        Inventory.instance.AddItem(equipment);
    }
}

public class Inventory {
    public static Inventory instance;
    List<IItemObject<Item>> items = new List<IItemObject<Item>>();

    public void AddItem(IItemObject<Item> _item) {
        items.Add(_item);
    }
}
```

More reading on [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't that `Equipment` is inherited from `Item`. The issue is you are creating a specific type from a generic class. `ItemObject<T>`-> `ItemObject<Equipment>`. There is no explicit or implicit method to convert an `ItemObject<Equipment>` to an `ItemObject<Item>`.

Where the implicit conversion would work is if you had an `ItemObject<Item>` and tried to add an `Equipment` in place of an `Item`. In this case, the `Equipment` would be implicitly cast as an `Item` before being passed to `ItemObject<Item>`'s method.